# 1 x chen hyd 2 y bang mum

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id name add1 add2
1   x   chen    hyd
2   y   bang    mum
```

i want to output like

```
id name add
1    x  chen
1    x  hyd
2    y  bang
2    y  mum
```

Comment: Does anything make sense?

Comment: Hint:  `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Add the row (3, z, dad, dad), and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION` like:

```
SELECT id,name,add1 from mytable
UNION
SELECT id,name,add2 from mytable
```

**EDIT:** for better performance you can use UNION ALL instead, that will give you the same result:

```
SELECT id,name,add1 from mytable
 UNION ALL
SELECT   id,name,add2 from mytable
```

Comment: Why not `UNION ALL`?

Comment: @jarlh since the returned rows are all distinct, UNION and UNION ALL will work the same

Comment: If you don't need to remove duplicates, do UNION ALL since it's cheaper.

Comment: @jarlh Yes you are right, did not think it performance based